# Does the nitrogen-based cryogenic freezing technology work equally well for all durian types, or only for a few types?

Tags: freezing, fruit, durian

Does the nitrogen-based cryogenic freezing technology work equally well for all durian types, or only for a few types?

Comment: If we don't know what you are trying to achieve, we can't define what means "works well". Why do you want to freeze your durian, and what would be an outcome in which the technology has worked well and what would be an outcome in which it has failed?

Comment: @rumtscho works well = properly conserve the quality of the product. Freeze to eat later.